# python - Downloading file from website using requests

Tags: python, file, web-scraping, python-requests, mp3

I'm trying to download mp3 files from https://www.alain-pennec.bzh/editions/livre-mp3/mp3/ with the following code :

```
import requests

def main():
    for i in range(0, 226) :
        URL = "https://www.alain-pennec.bzh/editions/livre-mp3/mp3/AP"+numberOn3Char(i)+".mp3"
        response = requests.get(URL)
        open("AP"+numberOn3Char(i)+".mp3", "wb").write(response.content)
        print(numberOn3Char(i)+" OK")

def numberOn3Char(i):
    ret = str(i)
    if len(ret) == 1 :
        ret = '00' + ret
    elif len(ret) == 2 :
        ret = '0' + ret
    return ret

main()
```

My issue is that nothing is being downloaded. I get no error and I don't understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
open("AP"+numberOn3Char(i)+".mp3", "wb").write(response.content)
```

to

```
 name = "AP"+numberOn3Char(i)+".mp3"
 with open(name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

and see if it works.

Comment: It doesn't work either

Comment: @Sam - Then I don't know what to tell you - it works for me. Try downloading only one file, using its actual name, and see if that works.

Comment: I assume it's because it's a professional computer, and I'm limited by the firewall

Comment: @Sam I doubt that, but you can try this: simply try; `url = "https://www.alain-pennec.bzh/editions/livre-mp3/mp3/AP015.mp3" response = requests.get(url) print(response)"`. If you get `200` then there's no problem w/ the firewall.